# Libre SSL fail to connect to proxy software on localhost

Tags: git, riscv, libressl

I am trying to brew install riscv-tools on my intel mac.
Due to Chinese Great Firewall, I have to configure a VPN.
Then I set http_proxy for my zsh terminal by

`export https_proxy=https://127.0.0.1:15236/`

however,when

`Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/dtc/manifests/1.6.1`,

an error is reported

```
curl: (35) LibreSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to 127.0.0.1:15236 
Error: riscv-tools: Failed to download resource "dtc_bottle_manifest"
Download failed: https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/dtc/manifests/1.6.1
```

Other file from the same address has been successfully downloaded, which is reported like:

```
Downloading https://ghcr.io/v2/homebrew/core/gmp/manifests/6.2.1_1
Already downloaded: /Users/jiachengzheng/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/a1986a80dafb4e42b8372268a00d8d14aa8294154c876ba82e7ce48db06885cb--gmp-6.2.1_1.bottle_manifest.json
```